# Java. Хочу ввести два числа и вывести большее через if и вот такая проблема

Tags: java, отладка, if

```
package Main;
    
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main {
    
       
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          
            
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            int a, b; 
            a = scanner.nextInt();
            b = scanner.nextInt();
      
            if (a > b)
                System.out.println("Liczba wieksza z liczb a = " +a+ " i b = " +b+ " jest liczba a");
            
            else 
                System.out.println("Liczba wieksza z liczb a = " +a+ " i b = " +b+ " jest liczba b");
            
        }
        
    }
```

---

```
Debug:
> Task :run
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:35)

> Task :run FAILED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет у Вас проблем с кодом. Он прекрасно работает. Вам нужно посмотреть как собирается проект (Maven, gradle) и запускается под какой командой. Проследите за файлами в папке проекта либо команды запуска.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a, b;
    a = scanner.nextInt();
    b = scanner.nextInt();

    if (a > b)
      System.out.println("Liczba wieksza z liczb a = " + a + " i b = " + b + " jest liczba a");
    else System.out.println("Liczba wieksza z liczb a = " + a + " i b = " + b + " jest liczba b");
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой у Вас компилятор?

Comment: @Влад У меня vs code

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо проверить параметры отладчика. Есть вероятность, что порт 5005 либо занят, либо закрыт. Можно для отладки поменять порт. Лучше использовать порты, начиная с 10000.

Comment: Уже разобрался, оказалось я просто не так проект создал